# python gitlab project.files.create gives Missing attributes: file_path error

Tags: python, gitlab

When I want to add a file to my repository via the api I always end up with the same error. Missing attributes: file_path. My filepath is test_api_upload.txt. When I try a full path. For example: /myproject/test_api_upload.txt I get the same error.

python-gitlab version

```
pip freeze |grep gitlab
python-gitlab==1.3.0
```

code

```
import gitlab
# private token or personal token authentication
gl = gitlab.Gitlab('https://gitlab.company.com', private_token='MYTOKEN', api_version=4)
gl.auth()

project = gl.projects.get('/my/project')
items = project.repository_tree() 
(works fine all items can be printed)

f = project.files.create({'test_api_upload.txt': 'test_api_upload',
                          'branch': 'master',
                          'content': 'file content',
                          'commit_message': 'Create testfile'})
```

output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/toon/.PyCharm2017.2/config/scratches/scratch_5.py", line 50, in <module>
    'commit_message': 'Create testfile'})
  File "/home/toon/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gitlab/cli.py", line 42, in wrapped_f
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/toon/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gitlab/exceptions.py", line 251, in wrapped_f
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/toon/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gitlab/v4/objects.py", line 1872, in create
    self._check_missing_create_attrs(data)
  File "/home/toon/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gitlab/mixins.py", line 142, in _check_missing_create_attrs
    raise AttributeError("Missing attributes: %s" % ", ".join(missing))
AttributeError: Missing attributes: file_path

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You will try this way:

```
import sys, os 
import gitlab

file_content = open(os.getcwd() + 'testfile.txt').read()
f = project.files.create({
                           'file_path': 'testfile.txt',
                           'branch': 'master',
                           'content': file_content,
                           'author_email': 'test@example.com',
                           'author_name': 'yourname',
                           'commit_message': 'Create testfile'
                         })
```

Comment: i was using `branch_name` is only `branch`. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Just realised I changed the key instead of the value for file_path in the original request. But by looking into it i found out that the docs where missing a few attributes. I made a pull request.
https://github.com/python-gitlab/python-gitlab/pull/483

```
f = project.files.create({'file_path': 'testfile.txt',
                          'branch_name': 'master',
                          'content': file_content,
                          'author_email': 'test@example.com',
                          'author_name': 'yourname',
                          'encoding': 'text',
                          'commit_message': 'Create testfile'})
```

I was confused by the 'file_path: testfile' tuple. Added a .txt to for clarification.